# Content-Blocking extension in safari does not work on XCode / iPhone?

Tags: ios, xcode, safari

I want to develop a content blocking extension for Safari in iOS and XCode.

I created a single view app with an safari content blocking extension. I added the following JSON into the blockerList.json:

```
[
 {
    "trigger": {
         "url-filter": ".*"
        },
    "action": {
         "type": "css-display-none",
         "selector": ".site-title"
        }
  }
 ]
```

I am testing in the iOS simulator in XCode, I have activated the Content Blocker in Safari already, but if I go to the website where the "site-title" element is (the filter is used on every website), the div layer is not blocked, it is visible.

The div layer is on the site definitely (I also checked it with Chrome in mobile view):

```
<div class="site-branding">
  <h1 class="site-title"><a href="http://www.website.com" rel="home">Name</a></h1>
  <div class="site-description">ContentToBlock</div>
</div>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Safarai Content Blocker works only on arm64 architectures.

Comment: And arm64 is iPhone 5S, iPhone 6 or iPhone 6-plus,plus the ipadAirs and the iPad mini 2 and 3.  Here's a great chart: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422447/what-iphone-devices-will-run-on-armv7s-and-arm64